# Tradingview pinescript indicator alerts not being triggered

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I've been trying to add alert functionality to an indicator. Here is what I have so far. I now have the option to create an alert for the indicator but the alerts are not being triggered when the conditions are met. I have tried various alert settings such as setting to bar close and such but not luck there.

```
//@version=4
study("Estimator",overlay=true,max_lines_count=500,max_bars_back=500)
h = input(8.,'Bandwidth')

src = input(close,'Source')

//----
n = bar_index
var ln = array.new_line(0) 
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to 499
        array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))
//----
float y2 = na
float y1 = na
float y1_d = na
//----
line l = na
label lb = na
if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to min(499,n-1)
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        for j = 0 to min(499,n-1)
            w = exp(-(pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
        y2 := sum/sumw
        d = y2 - y1

        l := array.get(ln,i)
        line.set_xy1(l,n-i+1,y1)
        line.set_xy2(l,n-i,y2)
        line.set_color(l,y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14)
        line.set_width(l,2)
        
        if d > 0 and y1_d < 0
            label.new(n-i+1,src[i],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=#39ff14,textalign=text.align_center) 
        if d < 0 and y1_d > 0
            label.new(n-i+1,src[i],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=#ff1100,textalign=text.align_center) 

        y1 := y2
        y1_d := d

d = y2 - y1
        
buyalert = if (d > 0 and y1_d < 0)
    true
else
    false
            
        
sellalert = if (d < 0 and y1_d > 0)
    true
else
    false
        
alertcondition(condition=buyalert, title="buy alert")
alertcondition(condition=sellalert, title="sell alert")
```

I tried adding buy and sell alerts, but I am lost at this point trying to figure out what is causing it not to trigger.

Comment: If `y1 := y2` that means that `y1` will always be equal to `y2` and therefore `d` will be equal to `0`. If `d` is `0`, `buyalert` and `sellalert` will always be `false` and the alert will never trigger

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. Can I get around that by placing the alert above  y1 := y2 where the arrow indicator labels are?